# Error handing with passing variables through functions that are yet to be defined through user error

Tags: python

I am building a menu that performs visualizations from an inputted DF through pandas. Via the menu, the first option selects 'load data' and from there I have a number of menu options that clean the loaded data, perform analytics etc.
Now if the data is yet to be loaded, how do I avoid the NameError if a user selects clean data before they have loaded the data?

```py
print(menu)
menu_choice = input(">>> ")
while menu_choice != '7':
    if menu_choice == '1':
        load_data()
    elif menu_choice == '2':
        view_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '3':
        clean_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '4':
        analyse_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '5':
        visualise_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '6':
        save_data(data)
    else:
        print("Invalid option!")
    print(menu)
    menu_choice = input(">>> ")
if menu_choice == '7':
    print("Goodbye!")
```

under load_data it will produce a data frame called 'data' if you were wondering where data came from.

So if someone is yet to select option 1, how do I handle the error if they select option 3 first?

Comment: Easy option is to catch the exception, using try and except, and print a message to the user saying load data before cleaning it. You can refer to this link for it https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-try-except/ OR you can have some kind of a flag which is set to true in case data is loaded. If not, you can again warn user to load data first.

Comment: how do I do that when im calling a function? Because the variable 'data' will attempt to pass through the function via clean_data(data) before I am able to catch the error... if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
print(menu)
    is_data_loaded = False #New flag to check if data is loaded.
    menu_choice = input(">>> ")
    while menu_choice != '7':
        if menu_choice == '1':
            load_data()
            is_data_loaded = True
        elif menu_choice == '2':
            view_data(data)
        elif menu_choice == '3':
            if is_data_loaded:
                clean_data(data)
                is_data_loaded = False
            else:
                print("Hey would you mind loading data first :)")
        elif menu_choice == '4':
            analyse_data(data)
        elif menu_choice == '5':
            visualise_data(data)
        elif menu_choice == '6':
            save_data(data)
        else:
            print("Invalid option!")
        print(menu)
        menu_choice = input(">>> ")

    if menu_choice == '7':
        print("Goodbye!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the data is loaded or not by adding a new variable, `data_loaded` here.

First, the variable, `data_loaded`, need to be set to False. Right right after calling load_data() (or inside the function), this variable must be set to True. Then, users can choose 2,3,4,5,6. If someone try to do 2,3,4,5,6 without choosing 1, it will print "Invaild option!", as follows:

```py
print(menu)
data_loaded = False # Newly added variable to check if data is loaded or not
menu_choice = input(">>> ")
while menu_choice != '7':
    # New condition to check if data is loaded or not
    # And if users choose 1 although the data is not loaded, print("Invaild option!")
    if (not data_loaded) and (menu_choice in [2,3,4,5,6]):
        print("Invalid option!")
        
    if menu_choice == '1':
        load_data()  # set data_loaded = True inside this function 
        data_loaded = True  # or right after this function like this
    elif menu_choice == '2':
        view_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '3':
        clean_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '4':
        analyse_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '5':
        visualise_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '6':
        save_data(data)
    else:
        print("Invalid option!")
    print(menu)
    menu_choice = input(">>> ")
if menu_choice == '7':
    print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: If this answered your question, you could mark it as answered :)

Comment: @LucasBlatchford Happy to help you. If you satisfyingi this answer (or another answer), please accept the answer so that other people can see what are the good way to solve your issue. I think other answers also helpful, so it would be great if you upvote for them. Thanks :)

Comment: I've upvoted you all but dont have the 15 reputation yet :) but you have absolutely got my vote!

Comment: @LucasBlatchford Thanks! However, you can "accept" answer although you don't have any reputation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you need a variable to store the status of your data.

NOTE: You need to put this line inside the while loop to let the user enter another option after the previous one done
For example:

```
print(menu)
menu_choice = '0'
status = {"loaded": False, ...}
while menu_choice != '7':
    # CHANGES
    menu_choice = input(">>> ")
    if menu_choice == '1':
        load_data()
    elif menu_choice == '2':
        view_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '3':
        # check it here
        if not status["loaded"]:
            print("You need to load the data first, Try again!")
        clean_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '4':
        analyse_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '5':
        visualise_data(data)
    elif menu_choice == '6':
        save_data(data)
    else:
        print("Invalid option!")
print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: Thats another issue I have, if I clean the data, go back to the menu and then want to visualise the data. It wont save the cleant data. How do I save the status into that while loop so that I can make changes and then continue to go back through the menus to make more changes to my 'data' data frame

Comment: You can easily save the state of each step by returning it in each function like cleaning, loading, ... For example: data = load_data(), data = clean_data(data), ...

Comment: Legend mate really appreciate it :) <3

Comment: Please upvote and mark as answered if you find it helpful. Thank you